# Radiobutton and checkbox like Dynpro OO controls?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I'm trying to create a dynamic OO-Dynpro and I don't know, how to create a Radiobutton or Input Control.

I found several Controls in the CL_GUI_CONTROL class, e.g. CL_GUI_INPUT_FIELD, which should be the Input-Control I`m looking for.

But I couldn't find radioboxes/checkboxes. Do they exist as OO-Control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The latest controls added were `CL_GUI_INPUT_FIELD` and `CL_GUI_COMBOBOX` in SAP GUI 730. I couldn't find anything new in the SAP notes.

The workaround is to use the HTML Viewer (class `CL_GUI_HTML_VIEWER`) where you can define any screen you want in HTML.